# Best way to create a folder on QNAP NAS over the internet via Python

Tags: python, directory, nas

What's the best way to create a folder remotely, over the internet, via python. Can I access it by IP and Port to access it or is it better to use something like an FTP module via python. Does anyone have experience on how to create a directory or make directory changes with python over the internet on a NAS? Something like `os.makedirs`. I'm not bounded to one specific solution. But for sure want to keep it as secure as possible.

Comment: If you do it over FTP (or SFTP, which is probably preferable), you need to expose that as a service to the internet. There's also the possibility to access an API (which you'd similarly have to expose), but I'd stick with something tried and true. I also suspect you want to do more than just create a folder, so you should probably consider all the operations you need to do remotely together and find a solution that meets all your needs instead of solving this one problem in a specific way only to find out the next problem needs another solution.

Comment: In the first place, I want to create a folder structure and make os.path commands. Best way would be to directly create folders there instead of uploading some. SFTP is more secure, right?